# Rails fields_for non-nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a rails app with the following:

```
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :habit_journals
  has_many :road_blocks

class RoadBlock < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :habit
  has_many :road_block_histories


class HabitJournal < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :habit
   end
```

I have a form that creates HabitJournals, although within this form I am trying to create RoadBlockHistories (which is just a rating on a RoadBlock over time)

I can't seem to work out how to create the form for this.

Habits have many HabitJournals and RoadBlocks. RoadBlockHistories don't relate directly to HabitJournals, but I would still like to capture these at the same form submission.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers
M

---

Sorry, I realised I need to add additional info.
This is Rails 4.1

A user will create a habit such as 'Be healthier'.
They then will create a number of road blocks to this habit such as 'Eating chocolate at night' and 'sleeping in instead of exercising'.

When the user views a habit they can add a journal entry (an update of how they are doing establishing the habit).

When adding a journal entry I'd like the user to be displayed with all their "road blocks" with a dropdown to select a rating (which is a mark out of 10 of how they are going with that road block). This rating would create a road_block_history object.

Hopefully this clarifies.

Cheers
M

Comment: Which `Rails version` you are using?

Comment: `accepts_nested_attributes`

Comment: I guess it would be easy when you create a `form` with `habit`,then you can easily `nest` the `road_block_histories`.

Comment: I updated with additional info.

Answer (score 1):

**Objects**

I understand what you want - still trying to consider how to get it working.

Something you need to consider is the *nature* of Ruby on Rails (Ruby in particular). Ruby is an [*object orientated*](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_object_oriented.htm) language, meaning everything it does is based around *objects*.

The problem you have is the object you're trying to create ("`RoadBlockHistories`") has no direct association to your "parent" object that you're trying to create ("`HabitJournals`").

---

[**`accepts_nested_attributes_for`**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

The "way" you'd surmount this problem typically is to use the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method - basically allowing you to pass data from a parent model to a child.

The important thing to note here is that this *only* works if your models are directly associated, IE that it's either a `has_many`, `belongs_to` or `has_many :through` for the model you're trying to create.

This is not magic - it's core Ruby. If you have a model you're trying to populate, if it has *associated* data, you'll be able to send that *through* your original model. However, as the language is *object orientated*, you cannot just populate an unrelated object without having that association

---

**Fix**

From what you've written, I would certainly look at treating the two forms as separate data objects (IE not associating them)

Perhaps you could do this (although it will need tweaking):

```
#app/models/habit.rb
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :habit_journals
  has_many :road_blocks
end

#app/models/road_block.rb
class RoadBlock < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :habit
  has_many :road_block_histories
end

#app/models/habit_journal.rb
class HabitJournal < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :habit
   has_many :road_blocks
end
```

Although this is not tested, nor do I think it would work, the reason I included this is to give you the idea about how you *could* pass an "unassociated" object through to Rails.

You can actually pass objects / data *through* others - so you could actually use something like the following:

```
#app/controllers/habit_journals_controller.rb
Class HabitJournalsController < ApplicationController
   def new
       @habit_journal = HabitJournal.new
       @habit_journal.road_blocks.build.road_block_histories.build #-> again, not sure if will work
   end

   def create
       @habit_journal = HabitJournal.new(habit_journal_params)
       @habit_journal.save
   end

   private

   def habit_journal_params 
       params.require(:habit_journal).permit(:x, :y, :z, road_blocks_attributes: [road_block_histories_attributes:[] ])
   end
end
```

If the associations are correct, this should allow you to create the following form:

```
#app/views/habit_jorunals/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @habit_journal do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :road_blocks do |rb| %>
       <%= rb.fields_for :road_blocks_histories do |h| %>
           <%= h.text_field :rating %>
       <% end %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You have a typo here in this line `@habit_journal - HabitJournal.new(habit_journal_params)` :)

Comment: And `road_block_attributes` should be `road_blocks_attributes` :)

Comment: Thanks Rich, I've been working through this and now for form build properly. Although when I submit the form I get an error "Cannot modify association 'HabitJournal#road_blocks' because the source reflection class 'RoadBlock' is associated to 'Habit' via :has_many." Any comment or advise?

Comment: Hmmmmm - let me have a a little think about it :) Thanks for the update!

Comment: To clarify, I did the following: 


class HabitJournal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :habit
  has_many :road_blocks, through: :habit
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :road_blocks
end